# Логика построения кода

Tags: java, javafx

Объясните по какой логике должна работать программа, у меня есть две `TableView`, выделяешь элемент в первой таблице, во второй таблице отображаются данные которые относятся к этому элементу, и так для каждого элемента из первой таблицы. Суть в том, что я уже создал все таблицы, все слушатели и т.д., но проблема в том, что во второй таблице у меня создается ровно столько строк, сколько их находится в первой, а так не должно быть.

*Я понимаю, что вопрос наверное не очень конкретен, но если я описываю все чуть более подробнее, получается слишком много текста и все говорят "фу я это читать даже не буду", мне не нужен код, мне хотя бы понять как создать эту взаимосвязь между таблицами, но если кому интересно скину гит*

```
 /**
     * Заполняет все текстовые поля, отображая подробности об адресате.
     * Если указанный адресат = null, то все текстовые поля очищаются.
     *
     * @param mainData — адресат типа Person или null
     */
    private void showContractDetails(MainData mainData) {
        if (mainData != null) {
            // Заполняем метки информацией из объекта MainData.
            numberContractLabel.setText(mainData.getNumberContract());
            counterpartyLabel.setText(mainData.getCounterparty());
            subjectContractLabel.setText(mainData.getSubjectContract());
            priceLabel.setText(Integer.toString(mainData.getPrice()));
            priceOnlyLabel.setText(Integer.toString((mainData.getPrice() - mainData.getSumСostsInt())));

            dateContractLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(mainData.getDateContract()));
            dateExecutionContractLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(mainData.getDateExecutionContract()));
            timeContractLabel.setText(DateUtil.format(mainData.getTimeContract()));

        } else {
            // Если Data = null, то убираем весь текст.
            numberContractLabel.setText("-");
            dateContractLabel.setText("-");
            counterpartyLabel.setText("-");
            subjectContractLabel.setText("-");
            dateExecutionContractLabel.setText("-");
            timeContractLabel.setText("-");
            priceLabel.setText("-");
            priceOnlyLabel.setText("-");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Как у вас так получается, мы, наверное, не узнаем) Нажали на кнопку, создали нужный список, нужной длинны, для него создали нужное количество строк в таблице. Откуда такое же количество?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko вот и я не пойму, если не затруднит, посмотрите тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/988529/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81-tableview-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0, я там старался указать максиматьно понятно и коротко что мне надо

Comment: Ну так сходу то не понять что и куда. Но в глаза бросаетс сразу contractTable.setItems(main.getContractData());
        filesTable.setItems(main.getContractData()); Зачем одно и то же в две таблицы?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko просто это основная коллекция, она использует класс `MainData`, но когда в `initialize()` я добавляю данные, я забираю нужные для меня

Comment: Где метод showContractDetails?

Comment: @SerhiiDikobrazko он для `Label` сделан, поэтому в данном вопросе как мне показалось смысловой нагрузки не несет за собой, но покажу на всякий случай (он создан для отображения правильной информации в поля `Label`)